# ¿Cómo pasar un parametro/argumento multilinea a un ejecutable mediante un batch?

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo el siguiente problema. Resulta que tengo un programa que necesita que se le pase ciertos parámetros/argumentos de esta forma.

**programa.exe    parametro1="valor1"     parametro2="valor2"    parametro3="valor3"**

El problema es que el valor de uno de estos parámetros es un texto que tiene varias líneas (muchas líneas) y no tengo ni idea de cómo hacer para setear este parámetro.

He pensado que lo más fácil sería tener el texto escrito en un archivo e intentar pasárselo haciendo algo así.

**programa.exe parametro1 = < "archivo.txt"**

Pero así no funciona. 
¿Alguna idea de cómo poder hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para  multilineas en `CMD` se usa el caracter `^`

```
C:\>echo linea 1^
More? continua en ^
More? otra linea
linea 1continua en otra linea

C:\>
```

---

para usarlo en un .bat es lo mismo:

`testmulti.bat`

```
echo linea 1^
continua en ^
otra linea
```

---

```
C:\>testmulti.bat

C:\>echo linea 1continua en otra linea
linea 1continua en otra linea
```

**Nota:** tener en cuenta que tanto el `^` como el `nueva línea` se remueven al procesar, así que si esperas un espacio entre dos palabras hay que ponerlo delante del `^` como en la segunda línea.

**Edit:** para agregar saltos de línea usamos el truco de [Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/1423096)

```
@echo off
REM Crear una variable para Newline (las dos líneas en blanco son requeridas)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

echo linea 1^
continua en ^
otra linea separada%NL%por un salto de^
 linea y%NL%%NL%dos mas ^
algo asi deberia funcionar
```

---

```
C:\>testmulti.bat
linea 1continua en otra linea separada
por un salto de linea y

dos mas algo asi deberia funcionar
```

Más ejemplos y explicaciones de cómo funciona el `^` y el `NL` en:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379861/1423096

y en:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455750/1423096

Comment: Perfecto!! Muchas gracias Alo, esto resuelve mi problema!! :-)

Comment: ¿Existe alguna forma de introducir un salto de linea adicional sin que se borre para que el programa.exe lo tenga en cuenta? he probado a poner esto \r\n o esto \n al final pero lo imprime tal cual, todo en la misma linea.

Comment: Estupendo!! Muchas gracias otra vez Alo!! Un Saludo!!